# How to group an object using reduce and spread operator

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects and trying to group it based on a value. It works with array.push method inside reduce callback. But I need an alternative with the spread operator.

```
const test = [
    {
        "shippingMethod": {
            "name": "product 1",
            "shipping": "Assembly Enabled",
            "method": "IN_HOME_ASSEMBLY"
        }
    },
    {
        "shippingMethod": {
            "name": "Product 2",
            "shipping": "Standard Shipping",
            "method": "FEDEX_GROUND"
        }
    },
    {
        "shippingMethod": {
            "name": "Product 3",
            "shipping": "FEDEX 2 DAY",
            "method": "FEDEX_2_DAY"
        }
    },
    {
        "shippingMethod": {
            "name": "Product 4",
            "shipping": "Standard Shipping",
            "method": "FEDEX_GROUND"
        }
    }
];
```

The following code works well.

```
const result = test.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.shippingMethod.method] = r[a.shippingMethod.method] || [];
        r[a.shippingMethod.method].push(a.shippingMethod);
        return r;
}, {});
```

And here is the output

```
{
  FEDEX_2_DAY: [{
  method: "FEDEX_2_DAY",
  name: "Product 3",
  shipping: "FEDEX 2 DAY"
}],
 FEDEX_GROUND: [{
     method: "FEDEX_GROUND",
     name: "Product 2",
     shipping: "Standard Shipping"
  }, {
     method: "FEDEX_GROUND",
     name: "Product 2",
     shipping: "Standard Shipping"
 }],
  IN_HOME_ASSEMBLY: [{
  method: "IIN_HOME_ASSEMBLY",
  name: "Product 1",
  shipping: "Assembly Enabled"
}]
}
```

You could see FEDEX_GROUND has been grouped together.

I wanted to use the spread operator instaed of `.push` to avoid mutation. Could someone suggest how I can accomplish it? When I tried spread, the array element was getting replaced instead of pushing into the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unconditionally reassign the property in the accumulator, and use `concat` to add the object onto the end of the array (which may be initially empty).

```js
const test=[{shippingMethod:{name:"product 1",shipping:"Assembly Enabled",method:"IN_HOME_ASSEMBLY"}},{shippingMethod:{name:"Product 2",shipping:"Standard Shipping",method:"FEDEX_GROUND"}},{shippingMethod:{name:"Product 3",shipping:"FEDEX 2 DAY",method:"FEDEX_2_DAY"}},{shippingMethod:{name:"Product 4",shipping:"Standard Shipping",method:"FEDEX_GROUND"}}];

const result = test.reduce(function (r, a) {
    r[a.shippingMethod.method] = (r[a.shippingMethod.method] || []).concat(a.shippingMethod);
    return r;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

If you had to use rest syntax, it's a bit uglier due to the array being spread possibly not existing:

```js
const test=[{shippingMethod:{name:"product 1",shipping:"Assembly Enabled",method:"IN_HOME_ASSEMBLY"}},{shippingMethod:{name:"Product 2",shipping:"Standard Shipping",method:"FEDEX_GROUND"}},{shippingMethod:{name:"Product 3",shipping:"FEDEX 2 DAY",method:"FEDEX_2_DAY"}},{shippingMethod:{name:"Product 4",shipping:"Standard Shipping",method:"FEDEX_GROUND"}}];

const result = test.reduce(function (r, a) {
    r[a.shippingMethod.method] = [...(r[a.shippingMethod.method] || []), a.shippingMethod];
    return r;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

That said -

- Mutating something inside a `.reduce` callback has no issues if there are no side-effects (which there aren't, in this case) - there's no problem with using `.push` here if you wished
- Some think that [`.reduce` wouldn't be all that appropriate here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg), because the accumulator is the same every time - a `for` loop could make more sense and be more concise

```js
const test=[{shippingMethod:{name:"product 1",shipping:"Assembly Enabled",method:"IN_HOME_ASSEMBLY"}},{shippingMethod:{name:"Product 2",shipping:"Standard Shipping",method:"FEDEX_GROUND"}},{shippingMethod:{name:"Product 3",shipping:"FEDEX 2 DAY",method:"FEDEX_2_DAY"}},{shippingMethod:{name:"Product 4",shipping:"Standard Shipping",method:"FEDEX_GROUND"}}];

const result = {};
for (const { shippingMethod } of test) {
  result[shippingMethod.method] ??= [];
  result[shippingMethod.method].push(shippingMethod)
}
console.log(result);
```

- Despite not mutating the array values with this approach, you'd still be mutating the accumulator. If you want to avoid that as well, you'd have to create a new accumulator every iteration.

```js
const test=[{shippingMethod:{name:"product 1",shipping:"Assembly Enabled",method:"IN_HOME_ASSEMBLY"}},{shippingMethod:{name:"Product 2",shipping:"Standard Shipping",method:"FEDEX_GROUND"}},{shippingMethod:{name:"Product 3",shipping:"FEDEX 2 DAY",method:"FEDEX_2_DAY"}},{shippingMethod:{name:"Product 4",shipping:"Standard Shipping",method:"FEDEX_GROUND"}}];

const result = test.reduce(
  (prevAccum, a) => ({
    ...prevAccum,
    [a.shippingMethod.method]: (prevAccum[a.shippingMethod.method] || []).concat(a.shippingMethod)
  }),
  {}
);
console.log(result);
```